# Select all users who are within a certain age range

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have users in a MySQL database, where their birthdays are stored in a `DATE` format (yyyy-mm-dd). I want to select users in the database with PHP who are between a certain age range.

What I have is a minimum age(18) and a maximum age(21). I know I can do something with BETWEEN, but the problem is that I only know the years and not the dates.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can do this?

This is what I'm doing currently:

```
function leeftijden($age) { 
    $morgen['day']   = date('d'); 
    $morgen['month'] = date('m'); 
    $morgen['year']  = date('Y') - $age;

    $datum = $morgen['year'] .'-' .$morgen['month'].'-' .$morgen['day'];

    return $datum;
}
```

Then I do this:

```
$maxDatum = leeftijden(18);
$minDatum = leeftijden(32);
$sqlRijder = "SELECT * FROM rijder WHERE geboortedatum between '".$minDatum."' AND '".$maxDatum."'";
```

But this doesn't work 100%.

How can I only select users who are between 18 and 21 years of age?

Comment: have you printed your dates to make sure the are correct?
also you can just do `date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-18 years"));` or `date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-$years years"));`

Comment: Of course it won't work 100% - cause the "age" is a number, it doesn't come in the format of date. So taking the current `date` and subtracting the age will give an inaccurate result.

Comment: alfasin...that is what i do in the leeftijden() function

Comment: @alfasin - are you saying that given someone's birth date, it's not possible to calculate their age?

Comment: I'm saying that this line: `$morgen['year']  = date('Y') - $age;` looks like it calculates the age in `years` rather than as a `date`

Comment: @alfasin - he's calculating the dates which are exactly 18 years ago and 21 years ago, and using those as a range.  If you look at the code more carefully, you can see he's appending today's month and day to the year X years ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply do it right in the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rijder 
WHERE geboortedatum BETWEEN 
    CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 YEAR AND 
    CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR
```

This way, you do not need a special PHP function to construct a DATE string. Simply pass in the numbers and MySQL will make the comparisons for you. Just make sure the higher number comes first in the `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Great a perfect solution @Zane Bien can you answer this i need it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000537/display-count-base-on-the-grand-child

Answer (score 4):

Try this :::

```
Select * from table where (DATEDIFF(dob, DATE(NOW())) / 365.25) between 18 and 21
```

Comment: Have not used MySQL, but wouldn't that fail to use indexes?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM rijder 
WHERE geboortedatum 
    between date_add(curdate(), interval -18 year) 
    and date_add(curdate(), interval -21 year)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM rijder WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), geboortedatum)/365.25 BETWEEN 18 AND 21
```